# Map NumPy array entries to dictionary value

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I currently have a NumPy array that looks like this:

```
>>> print(a)
[[ 1.      26.9952  30.6501  10.06952  1.61731]
 [ 2.      26.9952  30.6501  10.06952  1.61731]
 [ 0.      26.9952  30.6501  10.06952  1.61731]
 [ 2.      26.9952  30.6501  10.06952  1.61731]
 [ 3.      26.9952  30.6501  10.06952  1.61731]
 [ 2.      26.9952  30.6501  10.06952  1.61731]
 [ 1.      26.9952  30.6501  10.06952  1.61731]
 [ 2.      26.9952  30.6501  10.06952  1.61731]
 [ 3.      26.9952  30.6501  10.06952  1.61731]
 [ 2.      26.9952  30.6501  10.06952  1.61731]]
```

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
map_dict = {0.0: 'a', 1.0: 'b', 2.0: 'c', 3.0: 'd'}
```

What I want to do is convert all of the values in the first column of NumPy array `a` to the corresponding values in `map_dict`. Is there an efficient way that I can do that? The current method I'm using is going through a for loop and replacing the values iteratively as I go.

Comment: show us the current method so we can see how to improve it.

Comment: @Boendal Thanks for the suggestion. I don't mean to sound posh or haughty, but I intentionally didn't include the code in my question because I felt that my description and example were sufficient to get the question across and adding in a block of code would make my question unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
>>> map_dict = {0.0: 'a', 3.0: 'b', 6.0: 'c', 9.0: 'd'}
>>> a = a.astype(object)
>>> a[:,0] = np.vectorize(map_dict.get)(a[:,0])
>>> a
array([['a', 1, 2],
       ['b', 4, 5],
       ['c', 7, 8],
       ['d', 10, 11]], dtype=object)
```